# how to indicate shake is in right or left?

Tags: iphone

i want to implement next previous functionality using below function.

```
- (void)motionEnded:(UIEventSubtype)mt withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
```

But i dont know how to indicate in left or roght.
Please give me advice.

Comment: A shake gesture, by definition, travels both left and right.  I'm not sure what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way using this method to determine whether the shake was to the left or the right, it just detects a general shaking motion. You will need to process the accelerometer output in detail to achieve what you want. Look into the [UIAccelerometer](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAccelerometer_Class/) class and [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1018770/how-to-determine-the-direction-of-a-iphone-shake).