# how to detect direction of shake in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, iphone-sdk-3.0

I have an image of a bottle, whenever user shakes the device i want to move that image in that direction.
like up, down, left or right.

For example: if user is shaking the device in left direction i want to move that image in left direction.

i can detect shake event using

```
- (void)motionEnded:(UIEventSubtype)motion withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
if(event.subtype==UIEventSubtypeMotionShake)
{/*some code*/} }
```

but i dont know how to detect the direction.

i dont even if this is possible or not.
please help me.

Comment: What do you mean the direction of the shake? I wasn't aware that a shake has a direction.

Comment: A shake doesn't necessarily have a direction. I often shake things by rotating my wrist quickly in random directions or wagging my would-be tail in a back and forth motion.

Comment: For left and right, I posted my solution here : http://stackoverflow.com/a/29030985/1668837

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A shake is typically a back and forth movement. Use the accelerometer data to detect a sudden movement in one particular direction (e.g. left) or a tilt towards a different orientation.

Answer (score 0):

You can get user motion values using CMMotionManager class.Please refer the following link

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreMotion/Reference/CMMotionManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/CMMotionManager

Filter your acceleration and gyro dat detect direction of motion.