# How can i know the swinging direction of the ios device in ios programming?

Tags: iphone, gravity, uiaccelerometer, cmmotionmanager

I'm new to IOS programming, I don't know how to judge the swinging direction of a device.And I have searched a long time for this question, but I only find very little about this. Could someone help me? Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

I have search some post for you, hope to help.

[how to detect direction of shake in iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6223296/how-to-detect-direction-of-shake-in-iphone)

[How to determine the direction of a iPhone shake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1018770/how-to-determine-the-direction-of-a-iphone-shake)

Comment: I'm sorry, the meaning which I say is not this, I want to ask how to judge the directions(to up, to left, to right, to down) of shaking the ios device by users. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: @Abel_CN My mistake, I found some post, hope to help.

Comment: In my project, I need to detect the directions of x and y, And I found that the acceleration of x and y both become big, which make me very tangle!